# How can I programmatically generate images of different text on a static background?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a 1,300 games that I'm using in a frontend. I would like to generate 'banner' images that contain the name of the game on a static background image.

Ideally I would like to parse all the names in a list or array and run some software to create the images for me.

I wondered if this was possible/practical with PHP and, if so, how I would start to go about it?

The ideal solution would be some software that takes a static background image and co-ordinates of the bounding box (i.e. an area that the text must stay within). It then takes the name to be written and adjusts the size to fit the bounding box as best as possible. It then creates the image and saves that file and starts again with the next name in the array/list.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, the [GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) can do this. Use the [imagettfbbox()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function to calculate the dimensions of text.

Comment: This is brilliant! I'm just experimenting with the GD Library and already created dynamic text on an arbitary png file. You can add this as a solution if you like and I'll accept it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) can do this. Use the [imagettfbbox()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function to calculate the dimensions of text.

Here's an example that adds a left-aligned caption to the bottom of an image. If the text is too long to fit in at the specified size, the size is reduced to make it fit.

```php
<?php

$img_src = "mona-lisa.jpg";
$txt = "Hello World";
$font = "DroidSans.ttf";
$text_size = 60.0;
$baseline_y = 30;
$margin = 20;

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_src);
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$box = imageftbbox($text_size, 0.0, $font, $txt);
$txtw = $box[2];

// If text_size is too large, adjust accordingly
if ($txtw > $width - 2 * $margin) {
    $text_size *= ($width - 2 * $margin) / $txtw;
}

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefttext($img, $text_size, 0.0, $margin, $height-$baseline_y, $white, $font, $txt);

imagejpeg($img);
```

#### Output:

[image: Picture of the Mona Lisa with the caption "Hello World" across the bottom]

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I would have really struggled if you'd not pointed me in the right direction. Cheers